# Python matrix multiplication: sparse multiply dense

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Given the code snippet:

```
B = A @ M - T
```

where `A` is a CSR **scipy sparse matrix**, `M` and `T` are two **numpy arrays**.

**Question:** During the matrix operations, does numpy treat  `A` as a dense matrix, or `M` and `T` as two sparse matrices?

I suspect that the latter case is true since the resulting matrix `B` is not in the sparse format.

I also notices that this operation is much slower if I change the format of `A` to dense, which sort of contradicts my guess.

Comment: Here `A`the sparse matrix controls the operation.  It does one thing if the other object is sparse, another if dense (with different result type)

Comment: The `@` like `*` passes the task to `sparse.__mul__`, which in turn calls one of several methods depending on what the `other` is.  Follow the `[source]` link on this page if you want more details: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.__mul__.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy doesn't do sparse matrices. Scipy does the matrix multiplication (this means no multithreading, unlike numpy).

A is kept sparse but A @ M fills a dense array if M is a dense array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> A = sparse.random(100, 10, density=0.1, format='csr')
>>> B = np.random.rand(10, 10)
>>> type(A@B)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(B@A.T)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Note that some sparse operations still give matrixes, not arrays:

```
>>> N = sparse.random(100, 10, density=0.1, format='csr')
>>> type(A@B - N)
<class 'numpy.matrix'>
```